# Deploy failing in Netlify due react-bootstrap/button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, netlify

I am facing an issue while deploying my react js application to Netlify.
I have installed `react-bootstrap` in my application using `npm` and using bootstrap Button using the following import:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/button'
```

And it is running fine in my location machine and even *`npm run build`* has been successfully executed in my local machine.

However, when I am trying to deploy the same in Netlify it is getting failed with the following message:

> **Cannot find module: 'react-bootstrap/button'. Make sure this package is installed.**
>
> **You can install this package by running: npm install react-bootstrap/button.**

Whenever I am trying  to run **npm install react-bootstrap/button** it is throwing following error:

> npm ERR! Error while executing:
>
> npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t
> ssh://git@github.com/react-bootstrap/button.git
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
>
> npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>
> npm ERR! and the repository exists.
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include `react-bootstrap` in your `package.json`

Comment: Install the button with `npm i react-bootstrap` and then import via `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/button'` to treeshake the rest of the package from your bundle. Installing `npm i react-bootstrap/button` will fail (as it does) because that's not a valid npm package name.

Comment: @Medi react-bootstrap is already there in my package.json